# Flutter: Null check returns an exception for a second

Tags: flutter, dart

Device returns "Null check operator used on a null value" exception for a second, however i added checker to make sure value is not null. I am new in Flutter and i know this code is horrible, so can anyone gave some advices to make it more cleaner?

```
class _HotelPageState extends State<HotelPage> {
  HotelMode? hotmod;                              // object of class
  var isLoaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    hotmod = await HotelService().getHotelInfo();
    if (hotmod != null) {                            // checks if it has data
      setState(() {
        isLoaded = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: backgroundbgtheme,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            'Отель',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          toolbarHeight: 50,
          backgroundColor: backgroundtheme,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: Visibility(
          replacement: const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
          visible: isLoaded,
          child: ListView(
            children: [ HotelScreen(
              image: hotmod!.imageUrls[1],
                hotelname: hotmod!.name,
                price: hotmod!.minimalPrice,
                priceForIt: hotmod!.priceForIt,
                country: hotmod!.adress,
                rating: hotmod!.rating,
                ratingName: hotmod!.ratingName),
              HotelDescription(hotdesc: hotmod!.aboutTheHotel.description),
              const BottomButtonWidget()
              ]
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html, short video: https://youtu.be/zEdw_1B7JHY

Answer (score 1):

the data you're getting (** getHotelInfo**) is in Future. And UI will not wait until data comes.You should use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) in this case. or make all parametrs of HotelScreen widget nullable. Here is how you can use FutureBuilder in your case:

```dart
class HotelPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HotelPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HotelPage> createState() => _HotelPageState();
}

class _HotelPageState extends State<HotelPage> {
  
   Future getData ()async{
     return await HotelService().getHotelInfo();
    
    }
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: backgroundbgtheme,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            'Отель',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          toolbarHeight: 50,
          backgroundColor: backgroundtheme,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
        future:getData(),
         builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
           if(snapshot.hasData){
             var hotmod = snapshot.data;
           return ListView(
            children: [ HotelScreen(
              image: hotmod!.imageUrls[1],
                hotelname: hotmod!.name,
                price: hotmod!.minimalPrice,
                priceForIt: hotmod!.priceForIt,
                country: hotmod!.adress,
                rating: hotmod!.rating,
                ratingName: hotmod!.ratingName),
                HotelDescription(hotdesc: hotmod!.aboutTheHotel.description),
               const BottomButtonWidget(),
              ]
          );
           }else if (snapshot.hasError){
             return Text('Something happened');
           }else{
             return  Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
           }
         }
        )
      
    
    );
      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that the `initState` method is not waiting on the result of `getData`. It runs, `getData` is not done yet, the widget it `build` the first time and crashes, because for a specific time, `hotmod` *is* null. Only later it is filled.

So *at least* you need to make sure your build method does not crash when `hotmod` is null. Right now, it is invisible, but it still is build and crashes. So don't build it if it is null:

```
class _HotelPageState extends State<HotelPage> {
  HotelMode? hotmod;                              // object of class
  var isLoaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    hotmod = await HotelService().getHotelInfo();
    if (hotmod != null) {                            // checks if it has data
      setState(() {
        isLoaded = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: backgroundbgtheme,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            'Отель',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          toolbarHeight: 50,
          backgroundColor: backgroundtheme,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: 
          !isLoaded ?
          const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
          : 
          ListView(
            children: [ HotelScreen(
              image: hotmod!.imageUrls[1],
                hotelname: hotmod!.name,
                price: hotmod!.minimalPrice,
                priceForIt: hotmod!.priceForIt,
                country: hotmod!.adress,
                rating: hotmod!.rating,
                ratingName: hotmod!.ratingName),
              HotelDescription(hotdesc: hotmod!.aboutTheHotel.description),
              const BottomButtonWidget()
              ]
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

However, there is a solution already ready-made for this in flutter: [flutter-futurebuilder](/questions/tagged/flutter-futurebuilder)

See the example at [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle loading and error for future methods with `FutureBuilder`.

Create a **Future** method with return type **HotelMode**:

```
Future<HotelMode> futureMethod() async {
  HotelMode hotmod = await HotelService().getHotelInfo();
  return hotmod;
}
```

Use **FutureBuilder** for scaffold's body:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: futureMethod(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
        HotelMode hotmod = snapshot.data!;
        return YourListViewWidget();
      } else {
        return const Text('No data available');
      }
    },
  )
```

Comment: dont do things like `future: futureMethod()` read the second paragraph of official docs for more info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html or watch this short vid: https://youtu.be/zEdw_1B7JHY